# Get balance of each erc20 permit supported token

Tags: web3js, erc-20, tokens

I am trying to get the balance of each [permit supported token](https://belactriple9.github.io/1inchSupportedPermits/) with web3.js.
Do I need to write each token down and iterate trough them? If yes, how can I manage to get this.
Here is my code to get the balance from one token:

```
const contractAddress = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48"; 
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(balanceOfABI, contractAddress)

const result = await contract.methods.balanceOf(account).call(); 
const formattedResult = web3.utils.fromWei(result, "ether");
```

Comment: For this use case it's best to use an indexer solution like [The Graph](https://thegraph.com/).

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Thanks, I'll take a look into that.

Answer (score 0):

To get the balance of er20 token, I just made a simple loop to iterate trough every token that I defined:

```js
async function checkBalance() {
    const coins = [usdc, stake, wnxm, bal];
    const balances = [];
    for (let i=0; i < coins.length; i++) {
        const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(balanceOfABI, coins[i]);
        const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(account).call();
        const result = web3.utils.fromWei(result, "ether");
        balances.push(result);
    }
    return balances;
}
```